# Self Hosted ASP.NET Web API: how to embed images?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I switched my ASP.NET Web API from IIS-hosted to self-hosted. So far I had my images deployed in its own folder (and accessed them with `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`). Obviously this folder doesn't exist in a self hosted environment. How can I handle images instead?

Comment: You just want to access the images ? You *could* try - `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`

Comment: Current is null. But I think this is only part of the issue. The Images folder which I used to have (in my IIS installation) doesn't exist anymore...

Comment: Hi, I'm still stuck with this issue... Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. Here's what I did:

- set `Build Action` of each image as `Embedded Resource`
- replace my `MapPath` with the following piece of code:

`var resourcePath = "My.Namespace." + iconPath; //iconPath = subfolder.subfolder.file.ext
using (Stream imageStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath))
    {
        ...`